# A lower level of std::atomic<unsigned int>

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

I have a `struct` that consists of plain old data which I share between two dynamic linked libraries (or  shared objects). (Compiled with C++11).

One of the data members has to be an atomic type or, to be more precise, I need to be able to apply prefix `++` and `--` to it atomically.

I have concerns using `std::atomic<unsigned int>` for the member since I think that will tie the two libraries to using the same STL implementation.

So I'd rather use `std::uint32_t` as the member and apply atomic operations to that member within the libraries. Only I can't figure out how to do that, other than using a mutex which would degrade performance to an unacceptable degree.

In summary how can I do something like

```
std::int32_t foo;
atomic_increment(foo);
```

using functions available by standard C++11?

Comment: Your question is how to solve something when you cannot rely on the C++ standard, and you want an answer in terms of the C++ standard. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why not implementing this in a shared library using std::atomic, and export a stl-independant interface?

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Standard C++ doesn't respect the idea of different library implementations in different shared libraries (since it doesn't have a concept of the latter) and therefore does not consider your situation to exist. Therefore, there is no facility to support it.

In practice, though, just use `std::atomic` - any decent compiler/library on a platform that actually supports atomics should leave no trace of it at the machine code.